# How can I run specific task/s from the Airflow dag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, airflow, google-cloud-composer

**Current State of airflow dag:**

ml_processors = [a, b, c, d, e]

```
abc_task >> ml_processors (all ml models from a to e run in parallel after abc task is successfully completed)
ml_processors >> xyz_task (once a to e all are successful xyz task runs)
```

**Problem statement:** There are instances when one of the machine learning models (task in airflow) get on new version with better accuracy and we want to reprocess our data. Now lets say c_processor get on new version and reprocessing is required to just reprocess the data for this processor. In that case I would like to run c_processor >> xyz_task only.

**What I know/tried**

1. I know that I can go back in successful dag runs and clear the task for certain period of time to run only specific task. But this way might not be very efficient when I have lets say c_processor, d_classifier to be rerun. And I would end up doing 2 steps here:
2. c_processor >> xyz_task
3. d_processor >> xyz_task which I would like to avoid
4. I read about "backfill in airflow" but looks like its more for whole dag instead of specific/ selected tasks from a dag

**Environment/setup**

1. Using google composer environment.
2. Dag is triggered on file upload in GCP storage.

I am interested to know if there are any other ways to rerun only specific tasks from airflow dag.

Comment: This is not a good use case for airflow sadly. What you can do is that you clear c_processor and d_processor, and when both of them finishes then xyz_task will run just once.

Answer (score 1):

"clear"[1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#clear) would also allow you to clear some specific tasks in a DAG with the `--task-regex` flag. In this case, you can run `airflow tasks clear --task-regex "[c|d]_processor" --downstream -s 2021-03-22 -e 2021-03-23 <dag_id>`, which clear the states for `c` and `d` processors with their downstreams.

One caveat though, this will also clean up the states for the original task runs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bin. It sounds like #1 which I mentioned above but using this command would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, at the minimal, you will need to know what tasks to clean-up or backfill.